# Borel sigma algebra on Extended Real Line

Tags: general-topology, borel-sets

I am trying to understand the Borel Sigma Algebra on the extended real line. In order to do this, I must first understand the topology of the extended real line. In particular, I was wondering if $\{(a,b): a,b \in \mathbb{R} \}$ can generate (as in, use $\cup$ and complement of these to get all open sets) the extended real line topology. Since this set generates $\mathbb{R}$, we can find the complement of $\mathbb{R}$ and get $\{-\infty, \infty \}$, but I am not sure how to get the neighbourhoods of $\infty$ for example, $(a, \infty ]$.

Answer (score 3):

As you have discovered, the finite open intervals are not enough to generate the usual topology of the extended real line.

In order to generate the *topology* you need to explicitly declare $[-\infty,a)$ and $(a,\infty]$ (for $a\in\mathbb R$ or even just for $a\in\mathbb Q$ or $a\in \mathbb Z$) to be open.

(Remember that when you're generating a topology, taking complements is not a valid operation because complement is not supposed to preserve openness).

If all you're interested in is generate the *Borel algebra*, less can do it -- but you still need *some* way to distinguish between $-\infty$ and $\infty$. However including just, for example $\{-\infty\}$ or $[-\infty,0)$ among your generators would do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

The extended real line has a linear order, where $-\infty < x < \infty$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$,so also $-\infty< \infty$ and for $x,y$ reals $x < y$ means the same. This is just the "order completion" of $\mathbb{R}$.

Any linearly ordered set $X$ has an order topology, with as a subbase all sets of the form $L_a = \{x \in X: x < a\}$ and $U_a = \{x \in X: x > a\}$, the lower and upper sets w.r.t. all $a \in X$. We then have all open intervals $(a,b)$ as $L_b \cap U_a$ in the generated base, and all sets $[m, a) = L_a$ if $X$ has a minimum $m$ and $(a,M] = U_a$ if $M$ is the maximum for $X$ (if these exist).

So we get $[-\infty, x)$ as an open set of the extended reals, because we take the order topology on it, just as we do on $\mathbb{R}$.